# Trouble scraping Wikipedia articles using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_scientists) is a Wikipedia article containing a list of articles about notable computer scientists. I have to write a script that collects the following info for each one of them:

1. Their full name
2. The number of awards they have
3. The universities they've attended

I've already written the following code to gather the links to each article.

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_scientists"
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
lines = soup.find(id="mw-content-text").find_all("li")

valid_links = []
for line in lines:
    link = line.find("a")
    if link['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1:
        continue
    if link.text == "Lists portal":
        break
    valid_links.append("https://en.wikipedia.org" + link['href'])
```

It's also pretty easy to get their full name (it's just the tile for each one). However I'm having trouble writing a script that can get 2 & 3 correctly for each one.

What I have so far is the following:

```python
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

scientist_name = soup.find(id="firstHeading").string
    
soup.find(id="mw-content-text").find("table", class_="infobox biography vcard")
    
scientist_education = "PLACEHOLDER"
scientist_awards = "PLACEHOLDER"
```

Comment: What problem you have exactly? - please, specify. Also, consider that not every scientist listed had any award(s) listed on the wikipedia page, so, check closely and [edit] your question with the current and desired results.

Comment: There's a Wikipedia API and existing Python modules for working with either the article format or the rendered HTML; is there a reason you want to avoid these?

Comment: @tripleee Nope, no reason at all, I just didn't know it existed... Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try with the following code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_scientists"
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
lines = soup.find(id="mw-content-text").find_all("li")

valid_links = []
for line in lines:
    link = line.find("a")
    if link['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1:
        continue
    if link.text == "Lists portal":
        break
    valid_links.append("https://en.wikipedia.org" + link['href'])

for url in valid_links:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    name = soup.find(id="firstHeading").string
    edu = soup.find(lambda tag: len(tag.find_all()) == 0 and "Institutions" in tag.text)
    edux = [i.text.strip() for i in edu.find_next_siblings("td")] if edu else []
    awards = soup.find(lambda tag: len(tag.find_all()) == 0 and "Awards" in tag.text)
    awardsx = [i.text.strip() for i in awards.find_next_siblings("td")] if awards else []
    res = {"name": name, "education": edux, "awards": awardsx}
    print(res)
```

It returns the following output:

```
{'name': 'Atta ur Rehman Khan', 'education': ['Ajman University  King Saud University  University of Malaya  Sohar University  COMSATS University  Air University (Pakistan Air Force)  Qurtuba University'], 'awards': []}
{'name': 'Wil van der Aalst', 'education': ['RWTH Aachen University'], 'awards': []}
{'name': 'Scott Aaronson', 'education': ['University of Texas at Austin\nMassachusetts Institute of Technology\nInstitute for Advanced Study\nUniversity of Waterloo'], 'awards': ['Alan T. Waterman Award\nPECASE\nTomassoni–Chisesi Prize\nACM Prize in Computing']}
{'name': 'Rediet Abebe', 'education': ['University of California, BerkeleyHarvard UniversityCornell UniversityUniversity of Cambridge'], 'awards': ['Andrew Carnegie Fellow (2022)Harvard Society of Fellows (2019)MIT Technology Review Innovators Under 35 (2019)']}
....
```

However, I believe that there are better options for crawling this page, such as [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). Additionally, if that is the case, you could run your spiders on the cloud using a service like [estela](https://estela.bitmaker.la/docs/).